# Checkbox not working in nms formmail

Tags: forms, perl, formmail

I use [nms's FormMail script](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/) for my form as follows:

```
<form method=POST action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl">
            <input type=hidden name="recipient" value="mail@hotmail.com">
            <input type=hidden name="subject" value="subject">
            <input type=hidden name="redirect" value="-">
            <p>First Name:<input type="text" name="FirstName" /></p>
            <p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="LastName" /></p>
            <p>E-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" /></p>
</label>

  <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox1">Printing

  </label>

  <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox2">Web Development

  </label>
 </form>
```

I receive the mail with first and last name but that doesn't contain any info about e-mail input or checkboxes.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the nms script issue. Without looking at nms in detail here is what should happen.

On Submit, all your data inside the form should go to the pearl script.

However there needs to be functions in the pearl script that gets the data from the form.

Then the pearl script will assign that data to a variable or output that would then be processed by a mailing function.

So what you are looking for is the part in the pearl script where it gets the form information in order to send it via email, and make sure that your checkbox's are included.

*also as a side note, there seems to be a  in the wrong place just after the email input

Comment: Yes, you are right but as far as i know nms formmail should normally consider inputs others than text box.

Comment: in that case try adding a name variable to your checkbox's

so <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">

etc

Answer (score 0):

The nms formmail program handles all kinds of HTML form inputs without problems. If you want more help with this issue, please feel free to contact the project using our support email address - nms-cgi-support@lists.sf.net.

Comment: i asked this question to them right now, thanks. Once i receive the answer -if nobody answered yet- i will post it here.